# Simplifying does not give $(1/a)^x - a^{-x} =0$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify a complicated expression by replacing a^{-x} to (1/a)^{x}. I got the expression by hand and try to use simplify function to recheck whether it works. But a^{-x} is not canceled out and it is still pain. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to WM. have you tried anything?  Post that you have done so far.

Answer (score 3):

The relation under consideration is not true in the general case of complex values of $a,x$:

```
ComplexExpand[a^(-x) - (1/a)^x /. {a -> -1, x -> I}]
```

> $ e^{\pi }-e^{-\pi }$

This is true under some assumptions on the variables, e.g.

```
FullSimplify[a^(-x) - (1/a)^x, Assumptions -> a > 0 && x \[Element] Reals]
```

> 0

I think that was asked and answered many times.